# Linux illegal date format

Tags: linux, bash, macos, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

DAYS=${2:-0}
DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d' -d "2016-11-20 +$DAYS days")
```

I am trying to perform the above action in in my shell script but i keep getting this error:

```
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
2016-12-14 17:31:31,779
```

Not sure what is wrong

Comment: Are you using `GNU date`? `date --version`?

Comment: got this error: `$ date --version
date: illegal option -- -
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: It seems you are not using `GNU date`, works perfectly on it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a non-GNU `date` command may be the `FreeBSD` version on a Mac, use the `-j` flag.

```
date -j -v+2d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2016-11-20" +%Y-%m-%d
2016-11-22
```

to use a variable, just double-quote it

```
DAYS=2
date -j -v+"$DAYS"d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2016-11-20" +%Y-%m-%d
2016-11-22
```

Comment: To also set Date as a variable i have to add this: `Date=$(date -j -v+"$DAYS"d -f "%Y-%m-%d" "2016-11-20" +%Y-%m-%d)`

Comment: hey @Inian, it worked but i also wanted a DATE variable in my above question